# Error using SciPy 2D interpolator

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I have the following piece of code for `2D` interpolation:

```
myInterpolator = NearestNDInterpolator(XY_product, grid_data)
```

When I run this interpolator for a new data point:

```
new_grid_data = myInterpolator(new_XY)
```

I get the following error:

```
xi = self._check_call_shape(xi)
File "interpnd.pyx", line 133, in 
    scipy.interpolate.interpnd.NDInterpolatorBase._check_call_shape 
    (scipy/interpolate/interpnd.c:3261)
ValueError: number of dimensions in xi does not match x
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure `XY_product` and, specially, `new_XY` are what they're supposed to be?

Comment: @heltonbiker `XY_product` is the `np.asarray(cart_product)` in the following peice of code :
 `cart_product = []
  for element in itertools.product(ChromX,ChromY):
           cart_product.append(element)`

Comment: @heltonbiker Also, `new_XY` is the following: 

`shifted_cart_product = zip(ChromX_shifted,ChromY_shifted)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the description of `xi = self._check_call_shape(xi)` which illuminates where the error is coming from:

```
def _check_call_shape(self, xi):
    xi = np.asanyarray(xi)
    if xi.shape[-1] != self.points.shape[1]:
        raise ValueError("number of dimensions in xi does not match x")
    return xi
```

This basically means that `xi.shape[-1]` should be equal to `self.points.shape[1]`.